# $.post() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today i was using the j Query $.post(); method but i cannot find the reason for a problem which i encountered. The code snippet is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //When the button 1 is clicked
    $('#generateTable1').click(function(){

        //Get the Json data of the product low in stock
        $.post('database_to_phpJSON.php',{option:1},function(value){
            value=JSON.parse(value);
            console.log(value);
            alert("hi");
        },{dataType:'json'});

    });

});
```

now when i run the code than i did not get the alert message "Hi" and in the console of firebug i did not see the console.log output.
But as i removed the **dataType from my code every thing worked** fine...please let me knoe the reson for this.

Comment: Your php file is probably not returning valid JSON (impossible to say as you have not provided this info, but a good guess). You'll not be getting your success function, but your error function that you have not provided?

Comment: No dude its returning a JSON as response as....[{"product_name":"we","company":"tyr","quantity":"50","min_stock":"10"},{"product_name":"trf","company":"yu","quantity":"50","min_stock":"15"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when using `$.post`, you pass the dataType as a string only

```
$.post('database_to_phpJSON.php', {option:1}, function(value){

      console.log(value);

      alert("hi");

}, 'json').fail(function() {
      console.log(arguments); // will tell you what's wrong
});
```

And the result will be parsed automatically by jQuery when using the correct dataType

Comment: Then you're not passing back valid JSON, and you're getting a parse error.

Comment: but in my php file i am getting the json response as [{"product_name":"we","company":"tyr","quantity":"50","min_stock":"10"},{"‌​product_name":"trf","company":"yu","quantity":"50","min_stock":"15"}]

Comment: Not sure what you mean "getting", the dataType is for whatever you send back from PHP, not what you send **to** PHP ?

Comment: yes i am sending back a JSON....as i mentioned above . Using  echo(json_encode($json)); where $json is an array

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer and added a fail function, see what that says ?

Comment: the error is : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49350/discussion-between-user1334573-and-adeneo)

Comment: That's a parseError, so you're not sending back valid JSON. Check that there's no whitespace before or after the PHP tags, no BOM marks etc. as something is making the JSON invalid.

Comment: the JSON which i am returning from my php file is like this-> [{"product_name":"we","company":"tyr","quantity":"50","min_stock":"10"},{"product_name":"trf","company":"yu","quantity":"50","min_stock":"15"}]

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter is for data type, you only need to pass a string, but an object.

```
    $.post('database_to_phpJSON.php',{option:1},function(value){
        // and if you set the datatype to json, the value is already parsed.
        // value=JSON.parse(value);
        console.log(value);
        alert("hi");
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: on doing this i am getting ERROR JSON.parse: unexpected character